# GitLab CI Issues w/ variables

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to call an EXE with 3 parameters that are CI variables defined in GitLab, but the last variable parameter is not passed correctly.

Specifically, I'm calling nuget.exe to push a package to a local server running baget.

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` configuration (only relevant parts):

```
NuGetDeploy:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - tags
  tags:
    - csharp
  script:
    - cd $BUILD_PROJECT
    - mv *.nupkg "$NUGET_PKG_ID.nupkg"
    - nuget push "$NUGET_PKG_ID.nupkg" -ForceEnglishOutput -Verbosity detailed -NoSymbols -Source $NUGET_FEED_URL -ApiKey $NUGET_API_KEY -NonInteractive
    - cd ..
  artifacts:
    untracked: true
    expire_in: 4 weeks
  dependencies:
    - NuGetPack
```

The error occurs in the `NuGetDeploy` Job:

```
$ nuget push "$NUGET_PKG_ID.nupkg" -ForceEnglishOutput -Verbosity detailed -NoSymbols -Source $NUGET_FEED_URL -ApiKey $NUGET_API_KEY -NonInteractive
NuGet Version: 4.7.1.5393
Pushing Skiba.Testspace.NuGetTest.nupkg to 'http://baget.mycompany.org/v2/package'...
  PUT http://baget.skibapro.de/v2/package/
Please provide credentials for: http://baget.mycompany.org/v3/index.json
UserName: Password: An error was encountered when fetching 'PUT http://baget.mycompany.org/v2/package/'. The request will now be retried.
The HTTP request to 'PUT http://baget.mycompany.org/v2/package/' has timed out after 300000ms.
```

The odd thing is when I swap the Source and ApiKey parameters

```
- nuget push "$NUGET_PKG_ID.nupkg" -ForceEnglishOutput -Verbosity detailed -NoSymbols -ApiKey $NUGET_API_KEY -Source $NUGET_FEED_URL -NonInteractive
```

Then this error occurs:

```
$ nuget push "$NUGET_PKG_ID.nupkg" -ForceEnglishOutput -Verbosity detailed -NoSymbols -ApiKey $NUGET_API_KEY -Source $NUGET_FEED_URL -NonInteractive
NuGet Version: 4.7.1.5393
Source parameter was not specified.
System.ArgumentException: Source parameter was not specified.
   at NuGet.Commands.CommandRunnerUtility.ResolveSource(IPackageSourceProvider sourceProvider, String source)
   at NuGet.Commands.PushRunner.<Run>d__0.MoveNext()
```

Which means something is wrong with my CI config or GitLab's interpretation. `NUGET_FEED_URL` is set to `http://baget.mycompany.org/v3/index.json` and `NUGET_API_KEY` is set to an alphanumeric string without spaces. `NUGET_API_KEY` is marked protected in GitLab's CI config UI.

The `nuget` executable was manually installed and added to the system's global PATH env var. The Runner is on a Windows Server 2016 host and uses PowerShell executor. Executing the push command manually in PowerShell, replacing the variables with their configured values works as expected on that system. Accessing `/v3/index.json` from the runner's host succeeds without any authentication.

I've tried both `-Param $UNQUOTED` and `-Param "$QUOTED"` variants, no luck either. Any guesses what might be wrong here?

Comment: I think you should remove this question

Answer (score 0):

FYI: I forgot to set the master branch to protected, so the `NUGET_API_KEY` variable was empty all along. m(